# Firebase don't receive message when app is killed - Android Oreo

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, message, android-8.0-oreo

I know that it have a lot of questions about this theme, but no one works in my project, and I don't know why.

I'm using Firebase, if my app is OPEN or in BACKGROUND, his receive the message, but when I kill my app don't appear more.

Using Android 8.0

My codes:
AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/default_notification_icon" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />

    <service
        android:name=".service.PineFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".service.PineFirebaseInstanceIDService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

FirebaseMessagingService.java

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);

    Log.i("Msg", "Message received [" + remoteMessage.getData() + "]");

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new
            NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.default_notification_icon)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                channelId,
                remoteMessage.getData().get("title"),
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        mChannel.setDescription(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
        mChannel.enableLights(true);
        mChannel.enableVibration(true);
        mChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        notificationManager.cancel(id);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

FirebaseInstanceIdService.java

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {

    super.onTokenRefresh();
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d("Token", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
}
```

Code in C# to send the push

```
async Task SendPushAndroidAsync(Device device, InArgumentRequest push, Notification notification)
    {
        var applicationID = configuration["Push:Google:ApplicationKey"];

        var data1 = new
        {
            to = DeviceIdEnviroment(device.Token, true),
            android = new {
                priority = "normal"
            },
            data = new
            {
                notificationId = notification.Id,
                title = notification.Title,
                message = notification.Message,
                type = notification.Type,
                date = notification.DateCreated.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"),
                android_channel_id = "channelidandroid"
            }
        };
        try
        {
            var jsonBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data1);

            using (var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"))
            {
                httpRequest.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "key=" + applicationID);
                httpRequest.Content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var result = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest);

                    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        await UpdateStatusNotification(notification, true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await UpdateStatusNotification(notification, false, result.ReasonPhrase);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.InnerException.Message;
            await UpdateStatusNotification(notification, false, error);
        }
    }​
```

Thanks!

Comment: which phone are you using ? is it oneplus 5t

Comment: @nishant i'm using Asus Zenphone 4, but in Samsung S9 don't work too

Answer (score 1):

you need to go to settings> battery optimization> and disable it for your app. as that stops your application from running background services

Comment: but i want to receive the push notification when the app is killed :/, thanks for your quickly answer

Comment: you will get push notification when app is killed . by disabling the battery optimization from your app in settings

Comment: i tried this, and don't work yet, only on android 7.1 works fine

Answer (score 0):

The message `priority` [should not be nested](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) inside `android` and should have value "high":

```
    var data1 = new
    {
        to = DeviceIdEnviroment(device.Token, true),
        priority = "high",
        data = new
        {
            notificationId = notification.Id,
            title = notification.Title,
            message = notification.Message,
            type = notification.Type,
            date = notification.DateCreated.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"),
            android_channel_id = "channelidandroid"
        }
    };
```

It's possible you are not receiving the message because the device is in Doze Mode or the app is in App Standby Mode.  This is [explained in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#using_fcm).

After making the change to your message you can confirm that it is received with high priortity by calling [RemoteMessage.getOriginalPriority()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.html#getOriginalPriority()).

Comment: I tried the both ways and don't work yet, in two different phones and in one that have Android 7.1, this phone works fine

Comment: I'm not familiar with C#.  It looks like when you create your message, you are declaring the `priority` property in an `android` property.  It should be at the same level as `to` and `data`.  I updated my answer to show that.

Comment: I tried this too and don't works yet :/ i'm started to think to have a error in Android 8.0 for this case, because nothing work properly :(

Comment: Have you tried composing and sending a data message using the Firebase console?  Under "Advanced Options" you can set the data fields and priority.  I am able to receive high-priority data messages on Android 8 device after app is killed.

Comment: Yes I tried this now and don't work too... I think have something in FCM with Android 8.0 that blocks the services, because when we kill the application the all services is killed too in Android 8.0, if I do this with an Android 7.1 works well.