# com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver is not working in android Oreo when app is Killed

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-8.1-oreo

I used GCM for Push notification. In android Oreo, Push is received when app is in foreground & in backgroud. But push is not receiving when app is Killed (remove from recent apps).

I am in need to solve this. How can i solve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50882199/firebase-dont-receive-message-when-app-is-killed-android-oreo), make sure that the message priority [is not nested](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) inside `android` and should have value `"high"`. Additionally, it's possible you are not receiving the message because the device is in Doze Mode or the app is in App Standby Mode. This is [explained in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#using_fcm).

Based also from this [thread](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/378), FCM will stop delivering push messages if app is in stopped state. *Since the user intentionally force kills an app, Android assumes the app is not required and its FCM push services are killed as well. This is the normal behaviour of android.*

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've added this to your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Yes. I have already added this permission in my Manifest file. but still same. push is not receiving when app is Killed.